# how to write from crystal reports to a DB

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to kept track of every time a report is printed on crystal.

If I can write some information from crystal to a data base this may be possible, but I'm almost sure that this can not be done.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: How are you running Crystal Reports - through something like Crystal Enterprise, BO Enterprise or Crystal Info? Alternatively, is it being run from within another application via the API, or are all users running Crystal Report designer on their PCs?

Comment: I'm running the reports using the libraries that comes with .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest modifying the (C# ?) programs you are calling Crystal from, to write the desired information to the database.

Crystal Reports itself can't log this information, but if you were using one of the vendor's scheduling / distribution tools (such as Crystal Enterprise) then they would log this information inside their own databases.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of would be to set your report datasource to a stored procedure and include an insert statement to a log table.  Generally I would say 'Reports are for reading, not writing to a database' but you asked.